# concatenate inputs in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to concatenate all the arguments passed to my bash script except the flag.

So for example, If the script takes inputs as follows:

```
./myBashScript.sh -flag1 exampleString1 exampleString2
```

I want the result to be "exampleString1_exampleString2"

I can do this for a predefined number of inputs (i.e. 2), but how can i do it for an arbitrary number of inputs?

Answer (score 14):

```
function concatenate_args
{
    string=""
    for a in "$@" # Loop over arguments
    do
        if [[ "${a:0:1}" != "-" ]] # Ignore flags (first character is -)
        then
            if [[ "$string" != "" ]]
            then
                string+="_" # Delimeter
            fi
            string+="$a"
        fi
    done
    echo "$string"
}

# Usage:
args="$(concatenate_args "$@")"
```

Comment: Sorry to be strict, but -1 for bad shell style (very verbose and `[[ ... ]]` isn't portable). Use `test` instead, and see my solution for an alternative to using `${a:0:1}`

Comment: @JoSo Why isn't `[[ ]]` portable?

Comment: It's bash, not POSIX sh. (The same with `${a:0:1}`). While there are some who don't care because bash is installed on nearly any system, in this case really it has no use (use `test` alias `[ ... ]` instead).

Comment: @JoSo he clearly says that he is using bash.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, it's just a matter of style (and portability). We should give examples of good coding practices and yours isn't one.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ugly but simple solution:

```
echo $* | sed -e "s/ /_/g;s/[^_]*_//"
```

Comment: and wrong. Have you read the question?

Comment: @JoSo: yes, and this falls within its (poorly worded) specification.

Comment: However you interpret the spec, your solution is wrong. It doesn't even remove any arguments.

Comment: oh i see now, you're right, fixed

Comment: That's better now, but it still can't be completely right according to any interpretation. Consider spaces in the first argument.

Comment: yes, that's where "ugly but simple" comes in

Answer (score 3):

You can also use formatted strings to concatenate args.

```
# assuming flag is first arg and optional
flag=$1
[[ $1 = ${1#-} ]] && unset $flag || shift

concat=$(printf '%s_' ${@})
echo ${concat%_} # to remove the trailing _
```

nJoy!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piece of code that I'm actually proud of (it is very shell-style I think)

```
#!/bin/sh

firsttime=yes
for i in "$@" 
do
    test "$firsttime" && set -- && unset firsttime
    test "${i%%-*}" && set -- "$@" "$i"
done

IFS=_ ; echo "$*"
```

I've interpreted your question so as to remove *all* arguments beginning with `-`

If you only want to remove the beginning sequence of arguments beginnnig with `-`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while ! test "${1%%-*}"
do
    shift
done

IFS=_ ; echo "$*"
```

If you simply want to remove the first argument:

```
#!/bin/sh

shift
IFS=_ ; printf %s\\n "$*"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flag="$1"
shift
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS="_"
the_rest="$*"
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

In this context, `"$*"` is exactly what you're looking for, it seems.  It is seldom the correct choice, but here's a case where it really is the correct choice.

Alternatively, simply loop and concatenate:

```
flag="$1"
shift
the_rest=""
pad=""
for arg in "$@"
do
    the_rest="${the_rest}${pad}${arg}"
    pad="_"
done
```

The `$pad` variable ensures that you don't end up with a stray underscore at the start of `$the_rest`.

Comment: How does O.P. get the the desired '_' in between each arg?

Comment: You can set IFS so that its first char contains `_` to influence the behaviour of the `$*` concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
paramCat () {
for s in "$@" 
do
    case $s in 
        -*)
            ;;
        *) 
            echo -n _${s}
            ;; 
    esac
done
}

catted="$(paramCat "$@")"
echo ${catted/_/}
```